# T-SQL foreign key check constraint

Tags: t-sql, foreign-keys, constraints

When you create a foreign key constraint in a table and you create the script in MS SQL Management Studio, it looks like this.

```
ALTER TABLE T1  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_T1 FOREIGN KEY(project_id)
REFERENCES T2 (project_id)
GO
ALTER TABLE T1 CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_T1
GO
```

What I don't understand is what purpose has the second alter with check constraint.
Isn't creating the FK constraint enough? Do you have to add the check constraint to assure reference integrity ?

Another question: how would it look like then when you'd write it directly in the column definition?

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
my_column INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_T1 REFERENCES T2(my_column)
)
```

Isn't this enough?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First it creates the constraint and here you can specify whether data allready in the table should be checked or not against your new constraint. `WITH { CHECK | NOCHECK }`

The second part specifies that the constraint is enabled. `ALTER TABLE TableName { CHECK | NOCHECK } CONSTRAINT ConstraintName`

Comment: ok.. and it won't be enabled by default? Because in my opinion .. if I write a constraint when creating a table it should be enabled by default.

Comment: I will like to get an answer for your second question, all documentation i read says that fk constraint will enforce the rule in existing columns by default, so I would believe the second statement is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

The second statement is compelled by the "WITH CHECK" in the first statement.  There is a setting you can toggle to not do this.