# ms sql smo:how to script foreign key WITHOUT "Alter table MyTable check constraint MyForeignKey"

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, smo

I see server 2008 generated script:

```
ALTER TABLE [mytable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_mytable_id] FOREIGN KEY([id])
REFERENCES [mytable2] ([id])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE mytable CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_mytable_id]
```

Last statement is redundant, script works fine without it.
I generate scripts of foreign keys using SMO and want to avoid the last string. Can I do it?

Comment: I think it's redundant. I edited your tags to attract the attention of SQL Server experts.

Answer (score 0):

The check constraint section essentially ensures that your constraint is enabled.  It shouldn't be necessary as it should be enabled by your initial statement.

This question looks very similar to another on StackOverflow: [T-SQL foreign key check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927455/t-sql-foreign-key-check-constraint)